# How do I fail the train mission?

Tags: broken-age

I'm trapped in an endless, monotonous cycle. The only mission left is the train mission, but I can't work out how to fail it. All I can do is wake up the mountain and then I win. What do I need to do?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shout at him again and he'll shut the bridge again

Answer (score -1):

> Just wait until the Yarn Pal gets tired and lets go.

Comment: -1 He doesn't ever let go...